# pass parameter to custom label from javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, customlabel, parameters

I have a custom label that prints 'Enter at least 2 characters to search.'

I would like to make the 2 a parameter that gets passed in so that the user can adjust it at their discretion. So the label would be 'Enter at least {0} characters to search.'

My issue is that this is being called from javascript so I don't have access to apex:param. Is there a workaround for this?

Here is the javascript that is inline on a VF page

```
window.$Label = window.$Label || {};
$Label.Alert_message_for_search_function = '{!JSENCODE($Label.Alert_message_for_search_function)}';

function validate(){
    var input = document.getElementById('{!$Component.EntireRelationshipWidget.headerForWidget.searchAndClearButtons.searchBarForm.searchBar}').value;
    if(input.length < 2){
        alert($Label.Alert_message_for_search_function);
        return false;
    }
    searchFunction();
    return true;
}
```

Essentially I have a search bar that I want to impose a minimum character limit on. The javascript is called via commandButton

```
<apex:commandButton value="{!$Label.Search}" rerender="EntireRelationshipWidget" status="statusId" onclick="return validate();"/>
```

Comment: So, where do you call this javascript function?
I don't understand why don't you simply use something like {!param} where 'param' is property of controller of the page (or controller extension)

Comment: I am calling it via a commandButton. I have edited the post to reflect. Also how would I use the {!param} from a javascript method and passing it to the label for an alert?

Comment: So what do you have already tried? Did you try to declare a property in controller and try to retrieve its values through {!param} in your javascript function?

Comment: I have not been able to try anything because since this is a Label I'm not certain at all on how to pass params to it without an apex:param. however, since this is javascript I don't have that at my disposal

Comment: Look at using javascript remoting

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just adding a few lines to the javascript to manipulate the label. So the label says "Enter at least {0} characters to search." in the value section.

Then on the page javascript I used the .replace() method for strings to replace the {0} with the minLength that the user wants.

```
function validate(){
    var input = document.getElementById('{!$Component.EntireRelationshipWidget.headerForWidget.searchAndClearButtons.searchBarForm.searchBar}').value;
    var minLength = 3;
    if(input.length < minLength){
        var stringToPrint = $Label.Alert_message_for_search_function.replace('{0}', minLength.toString());
        alert(stringToPrint);
        return false;
    }
    searchFunction();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a property in controller.

If you have "YourCustomPage" and in its header you declare a controller for it

```
<apex:page controller="YourCustomPageController">
```

Then, in controller declare following

```
public class YourCustomPageController{
string goal, label;

public setGoal(string n){
   this.goal = n;
}

public getGoal(){
   return this.goal;
}

public setLabel(string n){
   this.label= n;
}

public getLabel(){
   return this.label;
}
public  YourCustomPageController{
    goal = '2';
    label = String.format('Alert_message_for_{0}search_function', new string[] {goal});
}
}
```

Then, in your page just use

```
function validate(){
    var input = document.getElementById('{!$Component.EntireRelationshipWidget.headerForWidget.searchAndClearButtons.searchBarForm.searchBar}').value;
    if(input.length < {!goal}){
        alert('{!label}');
        return false;
    }
    searchFunction();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: He would like the label to match the logic too.

Comment: Yes I am wanting to pass the parameter to the custom label

Comment: Ok, I have updated my code to include passing parameter to label using String.format function.